# Find out how many times a negative and positive number has been entered

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out on my program how to find how many positive and negative numbers have been entered from a user.

I have my question here:
"Write a program that keeps asking the user for numbers, until the user enters 0. After the user enters 0, the program should display the number of negative and positive numbers entered".

Also, I have my code so far here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NegativeandPositive 
{
    
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
int n;
       
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input an integer:");
       
        while ((n = input.nextInt()) != 0) 
        {
          System.out.println("You entered " + n);
          System.out.println("Input an integer:");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just a heads up for the future, Javascript is not the same as Java, I've updated your Tags so the correct SO users will see your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first question that I had so thanks for the correction!

Comment: Declare two new variables which holds the count of positive and negative numbers. Then in the while loop add a if condition which checks if entered number is positive or negative based the condition increment the positive counter or negative counter. After while loop print the same.

Comment: Java and Javascript are very different. This code is obviously Java. Please stop editing and adding the Javascript tag.

Comment: The Eclipse IDE is not specific to your Question. So I am deleting that tag.

Comment: What exactly is your *specific* question? Hint: "Please do my schoolwork assignment for me" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NegativeandPositive 
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        int n;
        int negative=0,positive=0;
       
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) 
        {
          System.out.println("Input an integer:");
          n = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println("You entered " + n);
          if(n==0) break;
          //Not using else
          //because if it's 0, below won't be executed anyways
          if(n < 0) negative++;
          else positive++;
        }
        System.out.println("Negative: "+negative+" ,positive: "+positive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Shazniq, I see where I went wrong and I see that I forgot to use"if", my mistake. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: @JordanTorchia no problem